# AS3/Flex/Air - how to capture initial value?

Tags: actionscript-3

The string values keep changing (see example below).  I want to get the initial (first) value.  How can I accomplish this?

Example:

```
var loading:String;
trace(""+loading);
O/P : 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

I want the first value (i.e. "1").

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
loading.charAt(0);
```

Or

```
loading.substr(0, 1)
```